# VueJS how to use _.debounce on data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debouncing

I'm building a little `vue.js`-application where I do some post requests. I use the `watch`-method to whach for api changes which then updates the component if the post request is successfull. Since the watcher constantly checks the API I want to add the `._debounce` method but for some reason it doesn't work.

here is the code:

```
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
export default { 
    data () {
      return {
        cds: [],
        cdCount: ''
     }
   },
   watch: {
     cds() {
       this.fetchAll()
     }
   },
   methods: {
      fetchAll: _.debounce(() => {
        this.$http.get('/api/cds')
         .then(response => {

          this.cds = response.body
          this.cdCount = response.body.length
         })
     })
  },
  created() {
     this.fetchAll();
  }
}
</script>
```

this gives me the **error**: `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Can someone maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I removed the `watch`-method and tried to add

```
updated(): {
  this.fetchAll()
}
```

with the result that the request runs in a loop :-/ When I remove the `updated`-lifecycle, the component does (of course) not react to api/array changes... I'm pretty clueless

Answer (score 3):

Mind the `this`: `() => {` in methods make the `this` reference `window` and not the Vue instance.

Declare using a regular `function`:

```
   methods: {
      fetchAll: _.debounce(function () {
        this.$http.get('/api/cds/add').then(response => {
          this.cds = response.body
          this.cdCount = response.body.length
         })
     })
   },
```

## Other problems

You have a cyclic dependency.

The `fetchAll` method is mutating the `cds` property (line `this.cds = response.body`) and the `cds()` watch is calling `this.fetchAll()`. As you can see, this leads to an infinite loop.

**Solution:** Stop the cycle by removing the `fetchAll` call from the watcher:

```
  watch: {
    cds() {
     // this.fetchAll() // remove this
    }
  },
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason, I dont get any data now!? :-/

Comment: Still same issue :-s

Comment: What do you mean? The request is made, but the `cds` and `cdCount` are not updated?

Comment: I get an empty list and the request is not even getting executed

Comment: Yes, but still it doesn't work. Feel free to check my updated question

Comment: What do you mean by *api/array changes.* ? What are you changing?